# Are "show" segues treated like a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

In other words, if I perform a show, I can expect:

- the new view will be put on top of the stack?
- once the new view unwinds, the new view will be destroyed?
- if you unwind back to the initial, then all views will be destroyed except the initial view?

Comment: It depends on you call it on a UIViewController or UINavigationController

Comment: @Arbitur if neither is a UINavigationController, then what happens to the view that's being unwinded ? Where does it go if it doesn't get destroyed?

Comment: If your controllers are not in a navigation controller, then "show" is the same a a modal presentation. When you unwind back, any controllers from the one you're unwinding from, up to but not including the one you're unwinding to, are deallocated.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you. Let's say I'm "showing" White -> Blue -> Black .  If I'm unwinding from Black to White , how can Blue know that it's being destroyed by Black's unwind? I want Blue to perform a specific action...such as removing observers for notifications.

Comment: You can remove the observers in the deinit method.

Comment: @rdelmar I put println in my deinit method, but it seems that it never gets called even when I "unwind segue" back to the root controller.

Comment: @TIMEX There can be many reasons why `deinit` is not called. But that has nothing to do with the question you asked! You asked what a show segue was, and you got the answer. Please don't turn one question into another in the comments. If you want to ask about why `deinit` is not called and your view controller leaks, ask a new question specifically about that, and supply the exact information needed in order to reproduce the issue. But that has nothing whatever to do with what a show segue is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Show" segue, new in iOS 8, is simply a shorthand for calling UIViewController's `showViewController:sender:`, which is documented here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/showViewController:sender:

And, for UINavigationController, here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/showViewController:sender:

As you can see simply by reading the docs, if the view controller in question is the child of a navigation controller, and we are not in a split view controller situation, this method is identical to calling `pushViewController:animated:` on the navigation controller. Thus, in such a situation, the "show" segue is identical to the "push" segue from previous iOS versions.

Comment: Thanks Matt. When a view calls unwind to a root view, will the view get destroyed? If not, what happens to it?

Comment: In the case of a simple navigation controller, not in a split view situation, `unwind` is the same as calling `popViewControllerAnimated:` or similar. Thus, any view controllers on the stack beyond the one we pop to are released. - However, this really is a separate question.